# Get list as array from Firebase with angularfire2(v5) and ngrx effects

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, ngrx

I have to tell you I'm getting crazy with it. I'm trying to get data from Firebase with AngularFire2(v.5) then work with it on @ngrx/effects and store it on @ngrx/store. Well, as I need the data with the keys, my code of effects looks like this:

**spaces.effects.ts**

```
@Effect()
  getSpaces$ = this.actions$.ofType(SpacesActions.GET_SPACES_REQUEST)
  .switchMap((action: SpacesActions.GetSpacesRequest) => {
    return this.afs.list<Space>('/spaces').snapshotChanges()
      .switchMap(actions => {
      console.log('action is ', actions);
      return actions.map(space => {
      const $key = space.payload.key;
      const data: Space = { $key, ...space.payload.val() };
      console.log('snapshot is: ', data);
      return new SpacesActions.GetSpacesSuccess(data);
      });
    }
  );
```

My "actions" comes with the data and the key, then I get the key for each item because then I could update and delete items easily. My database has 3 items with 3 keys. If I run this code and log it, first I can see all items in 1 array with their payloads and with the second log I see each payload as snapshot.

When I call GetSpacesSuccess, I'd like to send all snapshots I got (with key and item) then store it. The way I'm doing now dispatch this action 3 times and I can see only 2 items on the screen because the first one is overridden by the second one.

So, two questions: Is there any easier way to get the items from firebase with their keys then store them with @ngrx? If not, what am I doing wrong that my first item is being overridden and my action is being dispatched 3 times?

Please, I'm doing my best with it as I'm learning. Thank you!

**spaces.reducers.ts**

```
    case SpacesActions.GET_SPACES_REQUEST:
    return {
      state,
      spaces: null,
      loading: true
  };
    case SpacesActions.GET_SPACES_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
      spaces: [state, action.payload],
      loading: false
    };
```

**spaces.actions.ts**

```
export class GetSpacesRequest implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_SPACES_REQUEST;

}

export class GetSpacesSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_SPACES_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: Space) {} <<<<<HERE I'D LIKE TO GET THE FULL ARRAY WITH EACH KEY
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to store for each Item  also store its key. You are looking for [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

I would structure your feature as follows.

**spaces.actions.ts**:

Loading spaces requires no payload, while success has only an array of Space. I think you should build your `Map<string,Space>` in your reducer (`string` is your key).

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

/** App Models **/
import { Space } from './space.model';

export const GET_SPACES = '[Spaces] Spaces get';
export const GET_SPACES_SUCCESS = '[Start] Spaces get - Success';

export class GetSpacesAction implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_SPACES;
}

export class GetSpacesActionSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_SPACES_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Space[]) {}
}

export type All
    = GetSpacesAction
    | GetSpacesActionSuccess;
```

**spaces.effects.ts**:

I'm assuming you just need a method to fetch spaces. If you need to do other stuff, just edit this piece of code. `spaceService.getSpaces()` is supposed to return only an array of Spaces. So, create a new `Space` model and, on your service, map each json entry to a `new Space()`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';

/** rxjs **/
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

/** ngrx **/
import * as spacesActions from './spaces.actions';

/** App Services **/
import { SpacesService } from './spaces.service';

@Injectable()
export class SpacesEffects {

    @Effect() getSpaces$ = this.actions$
      .ofType(spaceActions.GET_SPACES)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(() => {
            return this.spaceService.getSpaces()
              .pipe(
                map((spaces) => {
                  return new spacesActions.GetSpacesActionSuccess(spaces);
                }),
                catchError((error: Error) => {
                  // Handle erro here
                })
              );
          })
        )
    ;

    constructor(private spacesService: SpacesService, private actions$: Actions) { }

}
```

**spaces.reducer.ts**

Here you build your map and you can also create a new action to return, for instance, a space given its key. I dont think you need any loading parameter here, I guess you are using it for some loading handling in your views, just use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your view and handle a loading animation with an `*ngIf` checking if there are spaces or not.

```
/** ngrx **/
import {createFeatureSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import {createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as spacesActions from './spaces.actions';

export type Action = spacesActions.All;

/** App Models **/
import { Space } from './space.model';

export interface SpaceState {
    keySpaces: Map<string, Space>;
    spaces: Space[];
    keys: string[];
}

export const initialState: SpaceState = {
    keySpaces: new Map<string, Space>(),
    spaces: [],
    keys: []
};

// Selectors
export const selectSpace  = createFeatureSelector<SpaceState>('space');
export const getKeySpaces = createSelector(selectSpace, (state: StartState) => {
  return state.keySpaces;
});
export const getSpaces = createSelector(selectSpace, (state: SpaceState) => {
  return state.spaces;
});
export const getKeys = createSelector(selectSpace, (state: SpaceState) => {
  return state.keys;
});

export function spacesReducer(state: SpaceState = initialState, action: Action): SpaceState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case startActions.GET_SPACES_SUCCESS:
            // Since we return this from effect
            const fetchedSpaces = action.payload;  
            const fetchedKeys = [];
            const keySpacesMap = new Map<string, Space>();
            fetchedSpaces.forEach( (space: Space) => {
                fetchedkeys = fetchedKeys.concat(space.key);
                keySpacesMap.set(space.key, new Space(space));
            }
            returns {
                ...state,
                keySpaces: keySpacesMap,
                spaces: fetchedSpaces,
                keys: fetchedkeys
            }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

And, finally, you should be able to get such parameters in your components like:

```
. . .

 keySpaces$ = Observable<Map<string, Space>>;
 spaces$ = Observable<Array<Space>>;
 keys$ = Observable<Array<string>>;

 constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
     this.keySpaces$ = this._store.select(getKeySpaces);
     this.space$s = this._store.select(getSpaces);
     this.keys$ = this._store.select(getKeys);
 }

 . . .

 ngOnInit() {
     this._store.dispatch(new spacesActions.GetSpacesAction);
 }

. . .
```

Of course add the new state to `AppState`:

```
. . .

export interface AppState {
  . . .
  space: SpaceState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @AndreaM16 for the most complete answer. I went through the night working on it and I ended up doing it different. Actually, in the learning process we make mistakes in order to get the knowledge. Probably your solution is better than mine and I'll study that, thanks. Please, if possible, I'd love to hear your comments about my solution.

Finally, after reading lots of documentation, my effects is now this one, I don't have any error catcher though:

```
private spacesList = 'spaces/';
@Effect()
  getSpaces$ = this.actions$.ofType(SpacesActions.GET_SPACES_REQUEST)
  .switchMap(payload => this.afs.list(this.spacesList).snapshotChanges()
    .map(spaces => {
      return spaces.map(
          res => {
            const $key = res.payload.key;
            const space: Space = {$key, ...res.payload.val()};
            return space;
          }
    );
    })
    .map(res =>
      new SpacesActions.GetSpacesSuccess(res)
    ));
```

**Reducer**

```
    case SpacesActions.GET_SPACES_REQUEST:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      spaces: null,
      loading: true
  });
    case SpacesActions.GET_SPACES_SUCCESS:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      spaces: action.payload,
      loading: false
  });
```

**Actions**

```
export class GetSpacesRequest implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_SPACES_REQUEST;

}

export class GetSpacesSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_SPACES_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: Space[]) {}
}
```

And, in my component, where I need the list:

```
 constructor(private store: Store<fromSpaces.FeatureState>) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new SpacesActions.GetSpacesRequest());
    this.spacesState = this.store.select('spaces');
}
```

Comment: Glad I helped you. A few points here, change your `effect` and, in general, all `rxjs` handling using `pipe` since it drastically reduces bundle size thanks to tree shaking. Take a look [at this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3?gi=3218b91fbbac). In general, on `effects` you just call some services and emit a success action or other action returning some data, while in `reducers` you 'play' with that data to return what you need. Move yoyur `store.select(...)` into your constructor.

Comment: Try to follow [ngrx-platform sample app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app).

Comment: Got your points. I've applied them. Thanks again for your comments.